# Омофоны (примеры)

Tags: лексика

Морепродукты и море продуктов.
Человек-оркестр; человек, оркестр.
Выпечь; вы - печь.

Эти сходные по звучанию, но различные в написании слова, называются омофонами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В вашем случае - полагаю, что нет. Омофоны невозможно различить на слух, в примерах это не так. Расставьте ударения - уже будут различия.

Если честно, выглядит как вопрос ради вопроса. Смысла спорить о термине не вижу, как и вообще о терминах. Хоть горшком назови... Без контекста все равно не понятно, зачем это надо - разбираться в значении этого слова, а в контексте всегда ясно, что имел в виду автор. Понятие омофона - этакая вещь в себе, на ней ничего глобального не строится, поэтому его неправильная трактовка ни к чему страшному не приведет.

Но в принципе омофоны с различным написанием (каламбуры) - в том числе и в два слова - возможны. В поэзии рифмы на каламбурах очень даже ценятся.

*На медведя вы, сосна,

Шишку бросили со сна.

А на нас, а на нас

Уроните ананас.*
(Яков Козловский)

*Первый свист и вой локомобилей

Дверь лингвисты войлоком обили.*
(Гумилев?)
Последний пример дает рифму-каламбур аж на восемь слогов, поскольку классический подход рассматривает рифмовку "...билей" и "...били" как правильную, то есть омофоническую.
Это даже не предел, кажется, есть и на десять слогов, но менее изящные и неинтересные.

Answer (score 0):

Нет. *Омофоны* — слова, ***полностью совпадающие*** по звучанию, но разные по смыслу. Смотрите в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B).

Примеры:

- в русском: *ко**т** — ко**д**, ро**к** — ро**г**, бло**к** — бло**г**, сто**к** — сто**г**, прив**и**дение — прив**е**дение, к**о**мпания — к**а**мпания, пр**е**зрение — пр**и**зрение, сп**е**ваться — сп**и**ваться, лёжка — Лёшка;*
- в английском: *hair — hare, mail — male, see — sea, meet — meat, I scream — ice cream, raw — roar, sun — son, sow — sew — so, great — grate, break — brake, jail — gaol, main — mane, hey — hay, lead (Pb) — led, your — you're, their — they're, pair — pear — pare, night — knight.*

Comment: А что же тогда приведено в вопросе? Побоку - по боку.

Comment: Первые только сходны по звучанию, но не совпадают. Второй пример какой-то неинтересный. В третьем — да, омофоны. *Побоку — по боку* тоже омофоны, если ударение делать на предлог.